# Search Arabic Text Contain Any Word SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, arabic

I have a problem in Arabic Full Text Search in SQL-Server, I want if the user Search for the word "الجامع تفسير" in search text in asp.net application and hit search button the result get all rows has any word contain "الجامع" or "تفسير" or "جامع"
[image]

Comment: i need to make sure: did you take care about the language setting when creating your index?

Comment: Hi Harry what do you mean by language setting when creating your index? could you please explain more

Comment: many thanks for your help, i set Language 1025 and it worked for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fulltext index in MS-SQL is kind of dependent on the language the contained text is written in. It tries to find "words" by using "breakers"

As i currently worked with full-text indexes, i know a little about it but unfortunately i dont know at all what your results means (sorry, dont know arabic letters).

Just remember the breakers and also that it only works on words that were identified between the breakers. Maybe this helps:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dc1a0efa-301b-425d-aa76-1e34144b18fd/using-full-text-search-with-arabic-and-english-data?forum=sqlsearch

[EDIT] 
List of language ids: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-fulltext-languages-transact-sql

Here some example from MS  where the language id is specified.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-fulltext-languages-transact-sql

USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG production_catalog;
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Production.ProductReview
 (
  ReviewerName
     Language 1033,
  EmailAddress
     Language 1033,
  Comments
     Language 1033
 )
  KEY INDEX PK_ProductReview_ProductReviewID
      ON production_catalog;
GO

Comment: many thanks for your help, i set Language 1025 and it worked for me :)